# How can I speed up this loop using multiprocessing or multithreading?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am afraid that I'm not doing the multithreading thing the right way, so I came here in search of wisdom. I have two arrays of addresses and I have to check if the address of the first array exists in the second array and in case it doesn't look for the most similar address in array 2.

The array that has the "oficial" addresses is called `directory` and the array that I need to validate is called `look_address`.

The code goes as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import threading
import queue

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID,name,q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name=name
        self.q = q
        
    def run(self):
        print(f"starting {self.name}")
        process_data(self.name,self.q)
        print(f"ending {self.name}")


locs = []
ratios={}
def process_data(threadName,q):
    while not exitFlag:
        queueLock.acquire()
        if not workQueue.empty():
            d = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            d = d.strip()
            if directory.isin([d]).any():

                locs.append(d)
                
            else:

                pos = process.extract(d,directory.values,scorer=fuzz.ratio,limit=50)
                ratios[d] = pos

        else:
            queueLock.release()

threadlist = ["T-1","T-2","T-3","T-4","T-5","T-6","T-7","T-8","T-9","T-10"]
nameList = look_address
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = queue.Queue(len(nameList)+1)
threads=[]
threadID=1

exitFlag=0
for name in threadlist:
    thread = myThread(threadID,name,workQueue)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID+=1
    
queueLock.acquire()
for addr in nameList:
    workQueue.put(addr)
queueLock.release()

total_steps = len(workQueue.queue)

tot_sec = 0
t0 = datetime.now()
while not workQueue.empty():
    total_seconds =(datetime.now()-t0).total_seconds()
    if total_seconds == 0:
            total_seconds = 1e-8
    progress = 1-len(workQueue.queue)/total_steps
    tot_sec+=total_seconds
    
    print("\rProgreso: {pr:.2f}% || Buenas/Errores: {gb}/{bd}".format(
                    pr = progress*100,
                    its = 1/total_seconds,
                    elap = timedelta(seconds=np.round(tot_sec)),
                    gb=len(locs),
                    bd=len(errors),
                    eta = timedelta(seconds=np.round(total_seconds*(total_steps-len(workQueue.queue))))),end="",flush=True)


exitFlag = 1

for t in threads:
    t.join()
print("\nExiting Main Thread")
```

Each request in `process.extract` takes around 25s (did a `%timeit`). Now, with the script above it doesn't seems to speed up the data processing. It has been running for like 2 hours and it has progressed by around 4.29%.

My two questions are:

1. Is the implementation of multithreading correct?
2. How can I speed up the data processing? Maybe run this on a VPS on amazon or google?

I want to understand why this is so slow and how I can speed things up.

EDIT: Changed from:

```
if not workQueue.empty():
     d = q.get()
     d = d.strip()
     if directory.isin([d]).any():

          locs.append(d)
                    
     else:
    
          pos = process.extract(d,directory.values,scorer=fuzz.ratio,limit=50)
          ratios[d] = pos
          queueLock.release()
```

to:

```
if not workQueue.empty():
     d = q.get()
     queueLock.release()
     d = d.strip()
     if directory.isin([d]).any():

          locs.append(d)
                    
     else:
    
          pos = process.extract(d,directory.values,scorer=fuzz.ratio,limit=50)
          ratios[d] = pos
```

Comment: Is your code even doing work in parralel? Since all your Threads need the Queue Lock for a full iteration of their while loop (aka locking at step 1 of the loop and realeasing as last step) there will allways only be 1 Thread in that loop, so the complete benefit of threading it in the first place is lost, but you do still have the overhead of threading...

Comment: Yes, I realized that and changed the code at that line, but the performance was not really improved. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As a first step you might want to replace fuzzywuzzy with rapidfuzz (https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) it implements the same algorithms as fuzzywuzzy but should be quite a bit faster (implemented mostly in C++ and comes with some algorithmic improvements)

Comment: Thanks @maxbachmann, I will try it :)